# Why I can move the position indicator (SetFilePointerEx) in file ONLY by 512 multiplier?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I try to move backward the position in file and it works only if I move by 512 bytes, why?

```
_file = CreateFile(path,
                   GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS,
                   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING
                   , NULL);

// THIS one works
LARGE_INTEGER distToMove = {-512};
    if(SetFilePointerEx(_file, distToMove, NULL, FILE_CURRENT) == FALSE)
    {
        // I got #87 error with GetLastError()
    }

// This one does NOT work
LARGE_INTEGER distToMove = {-3};
    if(SetFilePointerEx(_file, distToMove, NULL, FILE_CURRENT) == FALSE)
    {
        // I got #87 error with GetLastError()
    }
```

Comment: Like it says [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx), "There are strict requirements for successfully working with files opened with CreateFile using the FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING flag, for details see [File Buffering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc644950(v=vs.85).aspx)."

Comment: You're at the beginning of the file when you create it (i.e. FILE_BEGIN), right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Basically, if you open a file in unbuffered mode, you must move in disk sectors only (called volume sector size in the Windows API documentation.) In your case, these happen to be 512; but be aware that modern disk drives with 4Kn have sectors with 4096 bytes, so you really need to check the sector size first (or simply remove the NO_BUFFERING flag.)